# Out of memory. Type "help memory" for your options

Tags: matlab, vectorization, particle-filter

I am implementing particle filter in matlab. I am getting the above mentioned error if I try to vectorize my code. However, it works well if I dont vectorize. I need to vectorize it to save time taken by for loop. Any help would be appreciated. I have gone through other posts addressing same issues but however could not get any useful information for my perticular problem.

**Vectorized code**

```
n = size(X_kmin1,1);

X_k = proc_f(X_kmin1) + mvnrnd(zeros(n,1),proc_Q)';
ykp =  meas_h(X_k);

pyx = exp(-0.5 * (yk-ykp)' * ((meas_R)^-1) * (yk-ykp));
W_k = W_kmin1*pyx;

Wt = sum(W_k);
W_k = W_k/Wt;
```

**Error statement**

```
Out of memory. Type "help memory" for your options. 
Error in pfFilterStep (line 24) 
pyx = exp(-0.5 * ((yk-ykp)' * (meas_R)^-1 * (yk-ykp))); 
Error in Test1 (line 32) 
[X_k, W_k] = pfFilterStep(X_kmin1, W_kmin1, yk, proc_f, proc_Q, meas_h, meas_R);
```

**Working code**

```
%   Input:
%   X_kmin1     [n x N] Particles for state x in time k-1
%   W_kmin1     [1 x N] Weights for state x in time k-1
%   y_k         [m x 1] Measurement vector for time k
%   proc_f      Handle for process function f(x_k-1)
%   proc_Q      [n x n] process noise covariance
%   meas_h      Handle for measurement model function h(x_k)
%   meas_R      [m x m] measurement noise covariance
%
% Output:
%   X_k         [n x N] Particles for state x in time k
%   W_k         [1 x N] Weights for state x in time k

% Your code here!
n = size(X_kmin1,1);
N = size(X_kmin1,2);

for i = 1:N
    X_k(:,i) = proc_f(X_kmin1(:,i)) + mvnrnd(zeros(n,1),proc_Q)';
    ykp =  meas_h(X_k(:,i));

    pyx = exp(-0.5 * ((yk-ykp)' * (meas_R)^-1 * (yk-ykp)));
    W_k(i) = W_kmin1(i)*pyx;
end

Wt = sum(W_k);
W_k = W_k/Wt;
end
```

Comment: Anyway, your only solution is buying more RAM for your computer. You are out of memory.

Comment: I have updated the question with code. I am not running this on my local machine. Is there any reason why unvectorized code still works but not the vectorized? Both demands exactly same amount of memory. I guess only difference is the execution time.

Comment: To extend @AnderBiguri's comment as you don't seem to understand, why you get an `Out of memory` error: Your vectorized code doesn't work, because the allocation of temporary matrices, your final result matrix, etc. requires more "continuous" RAM as compared to processing only parts like vectors, etc. It's not always limited to the maximum amount of RAM, but the available "continuous" RAM, that can be allocated.

Comment: When you run it one by one, you overwrite the memory required in each step, you need less memory for whatever `proc_f` and `mvrnd` do. Similarly the size of `ypk` and `pyx` increase by quite a lot, in the loopy version they are way smaller.

Comment: All that said, make sure you are not doing matrix operations instead of vector operations (difference between `*` and `.*`) accidentally

Comment: Thankyou Ander Biguri and HansHirse. I hope the issues is only with the availability of continuous RAM memory and not coding syntax( I dont think there is a bad recursion going on with the code).

Comment: The code is not complete, so we can’t answer the question. `meas_h` is an underfined function. All input variables are undefined too. Can’t run the code, can’t know if it’s correct. But it is normal for vectorized code to need more memory than loopy code. You can try a compromise, looping over chunks of your data (a loop over groups of columns, rather than over individual columns); inside the loop you’d use your vectorized code.